# Editing the output screen

Tags: java, netbeans, colors, output

I am taking a screenshots for my output in netbeans, and i would like to make what user  enters only  coloured. 
I have tried using the screw driver at the left of the output screen then color and fonts but it only edits the body of the code ..
Is that possible, any suggestions.

Comment: Create a Swing GUI and edit the font and foreground color of the output JTextArea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In netbeans goto:

```
Window -> Options -> Miscellaneous -> Output
```

Here, you can change color for user input by changing value of `Input Color` option.

Answer (score 0):

Simple code that will change the background and text color of a JFrame component.

```java
input.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
input.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
```